# Media query not triggering on right pixel

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a very strange issue going on with my media queries. I have the following media query.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 995px) {
  //bunch of cool code here!

}
```

and it seems to be working, but it's triggering at 994px instead of 995px. This doesn't seem to be a big issue, but it's seeming to be a bigger issue the more I program because my nav bar is now interfering with my logo and that just isn't cool. It's a slight second, but still.

I have tried to set the media query for 996px and 997px, but that doesn't seem to help. Is there anything I can to do to fix this? Or is this a bug that I'm going to have to do some major programming to get around it?

And I have tested it using safari, firefox and chrome.

Comment: I know of bugs existing between browsers that offset the number by 20px due to the scrollbar. For instance, Chrome/Safari exclude the scrollbar dimensions, whereas the other don't.. Do you have a viewport set?

Comment: Can you provide the browser you used? Your media query should trigger right at 995px not 994px. Google chrome is a good reference for this, if you resize with the devtools open, it will give you an accurate pixel width in the upper right. I've tested it.

Comment: I do have a viewport set. This seems to be happening in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. :/

Comment: and Chrome says that the little jump happens at 995

Comment: Can you confirm you did reset your html and body markups with margin:0; padding:0; .css  ???

Comment: I dont see how margin and padding would effect a media query, but yes my body does have a margin and padding of 0. And I have done multiple browser resets...I have also been testing on different computers to see if this was an isolated issue or not...and its not.

Comment: I doubt it's related but I usually just use `@media screen`. Alternatively, is it possible an absolute positioned item is causing this?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried both, from what I've read it's better to put only in there. And no positioning! I am very proud of the fact that I built the whole site without any positioning! :)

Comment: and whats in my media query is really just hiding and showing elements.